# SQL multi join with table that should have same columns with different values

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT
billing_line.id,
billing_line.active,
billing_line.account_id,
billing_line.billing_measure_id,
billing_line.site_id,
billing_line.rate,
billing_line.range_start,
billing_line.range_end,
billing_measure.`name` AS measure_name,
billing_service.`name` AS service_name,
billing_field_value.id as billing_field_value_id,
billing_field_value.billing_field_id,
billing_field_value.`value`
FROM
    billing_line,
    billing_service,
    billing_measure
INNER JOIN billing_field_value ON (  ( billing_field_value.BILLING_FIELD_ID = 3 AND billing_field_value.VALUE = 'Option 2')
                                   OR( billing_field_value.BILLING_FIELD_ID = 4 AND billing_field_value.VALUE = 'Option 5'))
WHERE
    billing_line.ACTIVE = 1
AND billing_line.ACCOUNT_ID = 1337
AND billing_line.SITE_ID IS NULL
AND billing_service.ID = 7
AND billing_measure.ID = 15
AND billing_line.BILLING_MEASURE_ID = billing_measure.ID
AND billing_measure.BILLING_SERVICE_ID = billing_service.ID
AND billing_field_value.BILLING_LINE_ID = billing_line.ID
ORDER BY
    billing_service.SORT ASC,
    billing_measure.SORT ASC,
    billing_line.RANGE_START ASC,
    billing_line.RATE ASC
```

This, quite naturally, returns values where billing_field_value.value is 'Option 2' or 'Option 5'. This is for a filtering system which should be picking all 'Option 2' (for field id 3) but should ALSO be selecting only 'Option 5' (for field id 4)

The problem is that the results returned have got both 'Option 2'->'Other Options' as well as 'Option 2'->'Option 5' - so effectively any 'filters' past the first one are being ignored.

I realise that the 'OR' is part of the problem here, but because these fields and values are stored in the same columns but can have different values, using 'AND' means it will never evaluate to true.

This is probably a long complicated explanation for something simple-ish, but I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

Comment: It appears the problem is that inner joining the same table for the same columns but with different values will never resolve, and ORs will always select both. Technically problem not solved but i fixed the issue with running seperate select query to fetch IDs and then use IN() to limit accordingly. Meh.

Comment: With that in mind, if anyone has a more elegant suggestion, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want to return only records with `ID=3 and VALUE=2` or `ID=4 and VALUE=5`, is that correct?